# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5367: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, xml, django, postgresql, utf-8

- Django 1.6.1
- Python 3.2.3
- Apache 2.2.2
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Postgres 9.1.11

I'm getting this error when trying to import a serialized XML file. I exported it from one database that I was using for a development server, and moments later I import it to another database on a different development server (on the same machine). I'm very baffled as to why it's not handling the UTF-8 characters on import. I didn't do anything special. Plus, the same code worked when I last tested it. Here's the code I'm using to export & import, in an app's `views.py`...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.core import serializers

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def export_serial(request):
    '''
    This exports data using Django serializing.
    See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/
    '''
    XMLSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("xml")
    xml_serializer = XMLSerializer()
    xml_serializer.serialize(list(ThisModel.objects.all()) 
                        + list(ThatModel.objects.all())
                          + list(ThirdModel.objects.all()))
    data = xml_serializer.getvalue()

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/xml')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my-backup.xml'
    response.write(data)
    return response


@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def import_serial(request):
    '''
    This is for importing data that was saved/backed up, as serialized.
    '''
    xmlfile = '/home/zamphatta/path/to/my-backup.xml'
    serialfile = open(xmlfile,'r')
    data = serialfile.read()
    serialfile.close()

    for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("xml", data):
        deserialized_object.save()

    template = loader.get_template('z-style/index.htm')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'title': data,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I Googled & I checked out all StackOverflow questions that were related (but the answers don't clue me in to an answer for this), and still don't have a clue why this is throwing me this error. All I know is that non-ascii characters are making it puke, which doesn't make sense 'cause Python has no problem with UTF-8 characters and I'm not doing any weird stuff that would cause the code to suddenly treat it differently.

**UPDATE:** Here's a fuller version of the error message...

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /sdb/import/

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5367: ordinal not in range(128)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://coral/sdb/import/

Django Version: 1.6.1

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError

Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5367: ordinal not in range(128)

Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py in decode, line 26

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python

Python Version: 3.2.3

Python Path:    
['/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.2.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.4-py3.2.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py3.2.egg-info',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/dfy/code/zamphatta/',
 '/home/dfy/code/zamphatta/zamphatta/']
```

Comment: have you tried like this: your_string.encode('UTF-8')  ?

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace of that error?

Comment: Can you show us a traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Seems when the server was started up `python3 manage.py runserver`, the import would work just fine. It wasn't working when I was importing it through Django when Django was running on Apache via wsgi. So I'm guessing Apache was somehow interfering with it. It works now, as long as I import straight through Django.

Comment: All of my problems about ascii code errors , resolved with  decode('UTF-8') or encode('UTF-8'). these can solve your problem.

Comment: Where would I have put it though? It was just generated export & import that was handled by the same app.

Comment: please tell me exact line that you got error. data = serialfile.read() in import function?

Comment: Don't know the exact line now, but it was coughing up on a lot of lines. Always due to characters like '♯', 'á', and '博客'.

Comment: please try it: serializers.deserialize("xml", data.encode('UTF-8')) instead of serializers.deserialize("xml", data). and tell me the results.

Comment: @MortezaIpo Be really careful with the "hit it with a hammer until the error goes away" style of programming. If you encode a UTF-8 string twice, or `encode()` already-utf-8 text as `latin-1`-, you get garbage but no error. Please try to *understand* the situation and make an appropriate choice of fix for each specific situation.